# Mirror only a subdirectory from a git repository

Tags: git, version-control, repository, mirror

I've been doing some work for the University in a folder within their git repository.

There are other projects on the same repository divided in different folders and I would like to mirror my folder separately, so that it appears also in github.

Is it possible to do this without mirroring the entire repository and all the other folders?

Answer (score -1):

You want to make your folder a git submodule.